# How to update/refresh my graph (animated graph) after another cycle, with matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a file "00.csv", which can be updated each new cycle (the file 00.csv: is the result of a reading of another file, which extracts to the latter two values each time (each cycle).

here is the 00.csv file:

```
0, -1184.645675411964
1, -1184.653778859924 # first cycle
2, -1184.657325034754 # second cycle
3 -1184.657972735058
4, -1184.658582481392
5, -1184.658800896487
6, -1184.658844384850
7, -1184.658846846248
8, -1184.658825508352 # eighth cycle
```

I created a simple script, in order to draw a graph animate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)


def animate(i):
  graph_data = open('00.csv', 'r') .read()
  lines = graph_data.split('\n')
  xs = []
  ys = []
  for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
      x, y = line.split(',')
      xs.append(x)
      ys.append(y)
  ax1.clear()
  ax1.plot(xs, ys , color='blue', linestyle='dashdot', linewidth=4, marker='o', markerfacecolor='red', markeredgecolor='black',markeredgewidth=3, markersize=12)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation (fig , animate, interval=1000 )


#plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True)
plt.savefig("Plot_SCF-Energy_.pdf", dpi=150)
plt.savefig("Plot_SCF-Energy_.png", dpi=150)
plt.show()
```

the result (at a certain moment: eighth cycle) is as follows:
[image]

my problem is: after the eighth cycle, other cycles are added (i mean: both columns x, y) to 00.csv file like this:

```
9, -1184.658861339248   # ninth cycle
10, -1184.658863735214  # tenth cycle
11, -1184.658862250518  #  eleventh cycle
```

but the graph remains frozen in eighth cycle, it does not update !! ???

in addition,I followed [Matplotlib create real time animated graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376656/matplotlib-create-real-time-animated-graph), but I did not solve my problem.

**Is there a way to automatically read the file 00.csv after new cycle, in order to refresh my graph ??**

Answer (score 0):

The values you plot here seem to be strings instead of numbers. That does not make any sense.

Convert them to numbers first before trying to plot them.

```
xs.append(float(x))
ys.append(float(y))
```

You may also consider using some more efficient method to read the data.

```
import numpy as np

def animate(i):
    x,y = np.genfromtxt('00.csv', delimiter=",", unpack=True, invalid_raise=False)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: thank you, I tried with your script, but I achieved the same result.
after this attempt I realized that the problem is not focusing on the ploting graph, but it's about my file 00.csv. because I realized that "00.csv" does not update automatically.