# plot in matplotlib that continuously updates

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to make a live plot in matplotlib, meaning that the data is coming from a CSV file that keeps getting updated with new data. So far, I can't succeed to make the plot update continually.

My intention is that I want that with time passing the graph old point will get out of the plot figure.
Can someone help me please?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import csv
import time



fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


def animate(i):
    graph_data=open('DATA.csv')
    xs=[]
    ys=[]
    for line in graph_data:
        time,hrt=line.split(',')
        xs.append(float(time))
        ys.append(float(hrt))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs,ys,'b',linewidth=0.5)




ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [How to update/refresh my graph (animated graph) after another cycle, with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949189/how-to-update-refresh-my-graph-animated-graph-after-another-cycle-with-matplo)
but open the file outside of the function.

Inside of the function check if there is new data. It's not that good to use it from a file.

- You could count the number of lines that you read and reopen the file new each time and skip that number of lines.
- You could check the time stamp and read the last line.
- You could read all the data and plot the whole data again. Ok for little data.
- You could open the file in binary mode and check the number of bytes you read and then read up to the next line separator.