# Real time RGB graph from webcam

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, graph, rgb

I need to create a graphic that shows in real time  RGB from a video. I know that I have to capture a frame and plot 3 channels in a graphic and in the axis x plot time. But I am having a error. Webcam opens normally and a blank graph is showed at the screen. Does someone has any ideas that how can I write this code?

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = capture.read()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    if not ret:
        break


    def animate(i):

        b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for line in b:
            if len(line) > 1:
                x, y = line.split(',') #Getting the error: 'numpy.ndarray has no attribute split'.
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(y)
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)


    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()

    keyval = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if keyval == ord('q'):
        break


capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to display an interactive graph while receiving webcam frames.

- 1. You can use `plt.ion()`. The `ion()` method updates the graph while receiving inputs.

  - You may ask **Why not using FuncAnimation?**

    - From what I understand `FuncAnimation` method is not designed for `while` loop. `FuncAnimation` is useful for pre-computed frames. Here you can see the [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598124/update-frame-in-matplotlib-with-live-camera-preview) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376656/matplotlib-create-real-time-animated-graph).
- 2. How to get frames for each second?

  - We can calculate the `fps` (frame-per-second) value. For instance, if the `fps` value is 5, then 5 frames duration is equal to the 1 second.
  - We can count the frames using a variable and check whether the variable equals the `fps`. Then we add the frames.

    - ```py
      if frame_count % fps == 0:
          b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)

          line = [line for line in zip(b, g, r) if len(line)]

          xs.append(second)
          blue.append(np.mean(line[0]))
          green.append(np.mean(line[1]))
          red.append(np.mean(line[2]))
      ```
    - You may ask **Why not using `time.time for calculating the seconds?`**
    - I think using `fps` is more reliable than using `time.time`. I wanted to guarantee to get frames for each second.

Result:

[image]

I've obtained the result from the command prompt. If you debug it, you may get multiple images instead of one updated image.

**Update-1**

---

If you want to separate the channels you can multiply the each calculated variance with a different coefficient:

```py
blue.append(np.var(line[0])*0.02)
green.append(np.var(line[1])*0.03)
red.append(np.var(line[2])*0.04)
```

Result:

[image]

- You can also use `np.mean`

```py
blue.append(np.mean(line[0])*0.02)
green.append(np.mean(line[1])*0.03)
red.append(np.mean(line[2])*0.04)
```

Result:

[image]

**Update-2**

---

If you want to write the output data to the excel, you can use the [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) library.

You can install:

---

- pip environment: `pip install xlsxwriter`
- anaconda environment: `conda install -c anaconda xlsxwriter`

Three-steps:

---

- Step1: Create worksheet:

  - ```py
    book = Workbook('Channel.xlsx')
    sheet = book.add_worksheet()
    ```
- Step2: Initialize `row` and `column` variables:

  - ```py
    row = 0
    col = 0
    ```
- Step3: Write

  - ```py
    for s, b, g, r in zip(xs, blue, green, red):
        sheet.write(row, col, s)
        sheet.write(row + 1, col, b)
        sheet.write(row + 2, col, g)
        sheet.write(row + 3, col, r)
        col += 1
    ```

Output:

[image]

**Update-3**

---

- 1. Time

---

- In previous updates, the `fps = cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` which was wrong. The correct usage is `fps = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)`. Now we are getting the webcam's fps.
- 2. Speeding-up

---

- We were using `red`, `green`, `blue`, `xs` list structures for storing frames and seconds for both displaying and writing to the excel file.
- As frame data increases the list structures become a burden for real-time processing. Therefore one solution is dividing the displaying and writing operations.
- For displaying: `b_frame`, `g_frame`, `r_frame`, and `s_frame` are used.
- For writing to excel: `blue`, `green`, `red`, and `xs` are used.
- The main advantage is now we can reduce the storage for displaying frames. Since we are storing in `blue`, `green`, `red`, and `xs`.
- For instance: after two seconds delete the first frames.

  ```py
  del b_frame[0]
  del g_frame[0]
  del r_frame[0]
  del s_frame[0]
  ```
- Since the `b_frame`, `g_frame`, `r_frame`, and `s_frame` are no longer containing all the frames. The system speeds-up.

**Update-4**

---

`VideoCapture` blocks the application while the next frame is read, decode, and returned. Most probably this is the reason for the frozen camera.

One option is using `VideoStream` which process read, decode, and return actions concurrently by using queue structure.

To install `imutils`

---

- For pip: `pip install imutils`
- For anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge imutils`

Example:

---

```py
from imutils.video import VideoStream

vs = VideoStream().start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    
    if frame is None:
        break
     
    .
    .


vs.stop()
```

I tested `VideoStream` and there were no frozen frames or pause during the application.

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from imutils.video import VideoStream
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

fig = plt.figure()

plt.ion()  # Set interactive mode on

xs = []
blue = []
red = []
green = []

b_frame = []
g_frame = []
r_frame = []
s_frame = []

# We will be using Video-capture to get the fps value.
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
capture.release()

# New module: VideoStream
vs = VideoStream().start()

frame_count = 0
second = 1

is_new_frame = False

while True:
    frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break

    if frame_count % int(fps) == 0:
        b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)

        is_new_frame = True  # New frame has come

        line = [line for line in zip(b, g, r) if len(line)]

        s_frame.append(second)
        b_frame.append(np.mean(line[0]) * 0.02)
        g_frame.append(np.mean(line[1]) * 0.03)
        r_frame.append(np.mean(line[2]) * 0.04)

        plt.plot(s_frame, b_frame, 'b', label='blue', lw=7)
        plt.plot(s_frame, g_frame, 'g', label='green', lw=4)
        plt.plot(s_frame, r_frame, 'r', label='red')
        plt.xlabel('seconds')
        plt.ylabel('mean')
        if frame_count == 0:
            plt.legend()
        plt.show()

        second += 1

    elif second > 2:

        if is_new_frame:

            if second == 3:
                blue.extend(b_frame)
                green.extend(g_frame)
                red.extend(r_frame)
                xs.extend(s_frame)
            else:
                blue.append(b_frame[len(b_frame)-1])
                green.append(g_frame[len(g_frame)-1])
                red.append(r_frame[len(r_frame)-1])
                xs.append(s_frame[len(s_frame)-1])

            del b_frame[0]
            del g_frame[0]
            del r_frame[0]
            del s_frame[0]

            is_new_frame = False  # we added the new frame to our list structure

    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    frame_count += 1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
capture.release()
vs.stop()

book = Workbook('Channel.xlsx')
sheet = book.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

sheet.write(row, col, 'Seconds')
sheet.write(row + 1, col, 'Blue mean')
sheet.write(row + 2, col, 'Green mean')
sheet.write(row + 3, col, 'Red mean')

col += 1

for s, b, g, r in zip(xs, blue, green, red):
    sheet.write(row, col, s)
    sheet.write(row + 1, col, b)
    sheet.write(row + 2, col, g)
    sheet.write(row + 3, col, r)
    col += 1

book.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let me explain better what I need. While webcam is opened, I want to show a graph that has at the axis 'x' time in seconds and at the axis 'y' pixel value . Three channels, three lines showing the variation of the channel beyond the time. The code that I wrote above I am trying to do that. Passing a empty list while loop while is running. But I don't know whether my logic is right or not.

Comment: Do you want to display three channel's variation in a single graph?

Comment: Yes! Well, it might be in three graphs as well. But it would be better it was in a single graph. I need that because I am doing a chemical experiment which depends on color variation.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you please tell me if it is ok or not?

Comment: Ahmet, thank you! At the axis 'y' works perfect to me. Make every sense to use the mean of the channels. But at the axis 'x' still have a problem. I need really seconds. Counting from zero and finish just when I press 'q'. I need a real time graph. The graph is static,It is not moving.It shows me just a 'frozen' frame and a graph from this specific frame but I need all frames. My experiment measures the mean of color channels in function of time so I need a real time graph which has a real counting frames in seconds at the axis 'x' I tried to use like i = 0 and xs.append(i) but is not working.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you please tell me if it is ok or not?

Comment: It is working! I tried to use time.time as well but it didn't work. Your code is working but I had to add fig.canvas.draw() because plt.show was not working. I don't know why. Just three more questions: legend of the graph is not appearing, perhaps conditional frame_count == 1 would be equal zero? Lines are all together there is a way to separete them even pixel value are very close? Is there a way that I can get the data of the graph like a data frame pixel value x time? By the way, thank you very much for your support.

Comment: I've updated my naswer again for the 1st and 2nd questions. You can see the results under the update title. For your 3rd question I need time to build but in the mean time, you may achieve what you want by lookin g at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib/47166787).

Comment: Nice! I thought exactly like you! Multiply np.mean for a constant to separate the lines. Regarding 3rd question I mean to get data from the graph like at the end of the experiment I would have a excel sheet wiht pixel value versus time. I don't know if it happened with you as well but my webcam is with delay while running the interactive graph. Does it happen with you too?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can see the result of writing to the excel.

Comment: I fixed the problem that I had by adding time.sleep(0.01). So, I have realized that after 1, 2 minutes of recording webcam becomes so slow, very, very slow. I tried to record a experiment but I couldn't because webcam and graph became very slow(crazy delay) and after 2 minutes of recording and then graph and webcam closed together automatically. If I fix that I can use this code to make my experiment. Do you know what might be it?

Comment: I've never tested for 2 minutes. I will be working on the problem today

Comment: I've updated my answer, could you please check the update-3 and below code?

Comment: I have tested and it is so much better but still has a delay. I need to record my experiment at least for 10 minutes because about in 5 minutes color starts to change. I tried today is so much better but still has a delay and after some time camera is like frozen.Read and freeze. Read and Freeze. It is faster than before but it is freezing yet. I could't record my experiment. Do you think if we delate more frames as it increases, might speeds up ? In your upadte code you delete just the initial frames, right?

Comment: Yes I update the code by deleting initial frames in the `b_frame`, `g_frame`, `r_frame` and `s_frames`.  So I think I found a solution for frozen frames, using `VideoStream`. I tested for 10 minutes and there weren't any frozen frame or delays. You can check it under the Update-4.

Comment: Did you get it? No frozen frames anymore? I tried to record an experiment right now with your update code but I couldn’t still. Recording is still freezing. I thought it was my computer but I am using a good alienware to code and record my experiments. So, I don’t know : ( It is hard. My master degree depends on that hahaha. Thanks for your supporting, bro.

Comment: That's strange, I mean I did not have any frozen frames during my recording. Are you using windows? if so maybe it is better to stop background processes and then run the code via command-prompt via administrator rights. Still, you can do the same if you are using Linux. In mac, there was no problem.

Comment: Any delay?Weird. I am still having delay. You make a movement and take 2, 3s to read. Yes, I am using windows. I did what you wrote. Stoped bckground process and cod via prompt but recording is freezing yet.

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to increase the fps? To stop delaying? I still have this problem.